# how to change the location of a datasource in Power BI (Desktop)

Tags: powerbi

I have built a power bi desktop dashboard

it was for myself only so i put the datasource (.mdb) in my desktop

Now other employees want this dashboard.

but the problem that powerbi cannot find the source as it is pointing at my desktop ( even if other put the source file in their desktop, still cannot find it)

i think it looks at "c:\users(my name)\desktop

I want to change the data source location so it points at c:\data so everyone can create this folder in their computers

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a parameter for where you want to look for the file.

[image]

You can then edit your query to use the parameter.

[image]

Once done you will be able to edit the parameter from the main interface. Users can be shown how to set their own path.

[image]